# Change a loaded image based on a NSUserDefaults setting

Tags: xcode

Hope you can help me with this.
I have an app that needs to show one of two maps via the setting of a UISwitch. The settings.bundle is all set up and I am trying to write an If statement to determine if the switch is on or off, and to display the right image.

```
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
BOOL Enabled = [defaults boolForKey:@"zones_preference"];

if (Enabled == @"Enabled") {
    [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"withzones.jpg"]];
}
else {
    [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"withoutzones.jpg"]];
}
```

This builds without error, but doesn't load the image into the ScrollView. Could anyone advise on where I am going wrong?

Comment: Set breakpoints or NSLogs in if and in else and check which path the app takes.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the code you've posted only creates a `UIImageView` object and doesn't do anything more. It's a leak too.

There's one more error in the line

```
if (Enabled == @"Enabled") {
```

Here, you are comparing a boolean to a string which will evaluate to false automatically so it needs to be corrected too.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
BOOL enabled = [defaults boolForKey:@"zones_preference"];

UIImageView * imageView;
if ( enabled ) {
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"withzones.jpg"]];
} else {
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"withoutzones.jpg"]];
}

imageView.frame = imageViewFrame; // Where "imageViewFrame" is an appropriate frame.
[scrollView addSubview:imageView];
[imageView release];
```

Comment: I have carried on with this issue and all works well, but I think I have the if/else in the wrong place. I have a mainViewController, which does all the main work. An OptionsViewcontroller presents NSUserdefaults connected to the Settings.bundle. When the user clicks a Done button and it saves the settings. I need the If/else to tell if they have enabled the Withzones, and show image with zones, or disabled and shows the standard image. I have this as part of the ViewDidLoad on the main view, but may need to be part of the Done action. Not sure how to affect the main view from the Done button.

Answer (score 0):

Deepak, that was very useful and thank you. I had been working with a variable, but the mistake I had made was that I was trying to add the setup of the variable in with the creation of the UIImageView.

I'll work with this and see how I get on.